# Trying to access array offset on value of type null in After swich on php 7.4

Tags: php

After swich on php 7.4 coming errors in log. Opencart, .tpl file. Plese help to solve the problem.

```
Array to string conversion in view/template/module/dsfirewall/dsfirewall.tpl on line 36
2023-04-09 9:19:46 - PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: Array in view/template/module/dsfirewall/dsfirewall.tpl on line 36
2023-04-09 9:19:46 - PHP Notice:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in view/template/module/dsfirewall/dsfirewall.tpl on line 36
2023-04-09 9:19:46 - PHP Notice:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in view/template/module/dsfirewall/dsfirewall.tpl on line 36
```

**36 -----  php echo $$value[0]['security_name'];?>**

```
<style>
.on{
color:green;
}
.off{
color:red;
}
</style>
<div class="table-responsive">
<div style="text-align: right;">
<a target="_blank" href="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; ?>/logs_<?php echo md5($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);?>.txt"><span style="color:rgb(0, 121, 252)"><?php echo $ds_firewall_statistic_00;?></span></a>
</div>
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th><?php echo $ds_firewall_statistic_1;?></th>
            <th><?php echo $ds_firewall_statistic_2;?></th>
            <th><?php echo $ds_firewall_statistic_3;?></th>
            <th><?php echo $ds_firewall_statistic_4;?></th>
            <th><?php echo $ds_firewall_statistic_5;?></th>
            <th><?php echo $ds_firewall_statistic_6;?></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php
        $i_string  = 0;
        foreach ($data_stat as $key => $value) {$i_string++; 
        if ($value[0]['security_name'] == "dsfirewall_uploadfilemax"){ continue;}
        if ($value[0]['security_name'] == "dsfirewall_uploadfile"){ continue;}
        if ($value[0]['security_name'] == "dsfirewall_uploadfilesys"){ continue;}
        ?>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row"><?php echo $i_string;?></th>
            
        <td><?php echo $$value[0]['security_name'];?></td>
            
        
            <?php
            $n_setting = $value[0]['security_name'];
            /*
            echo"<pre>"; 
            print_r($n_setting);
            echo"</pre>";
            */
            switch ($n_setting ) {
                case 'dsfirewall_uploadfilemax':
                    {
                         if (!isset($modules[1]['dsfirewall_size'])){
                        $modules[1]['dsfirewall_size']="";
                        }
                        
                        if (is_numeric($modules[1]['dsfirewall_size'])){
                        echo '<td class="on" >'.$ds_firewall_statistic_7.'</td>';
                        } else {
                        echo '<td class="off">'.$ds_firewall_statistic_8.'</td>';
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case 'dsfirewall_uploadfile':
                    {
                    isset($modules[1]['dsfirewall_allow'])?$v_allow_select = $modules[1]['dsfirewall_allow']:$v_allow_select = '0';
                    
                        if ($v_allow_select == "0")
                        {
                        echo '<td class="off">'.$ds_firewall_statistic_8.'</td>';
                        }
                        if ($v_allow_select == "1")
                        {
                        echo '<td class="off">'.$ds_firewall_statistic_8.'</td>';
                        } 
                        if ($v_allow_select == "2")
                        {
                        echo '<td class="on" >'.$ds_firewall_statistic_7.'</td>';
                        } 
                    
                    
                    }
                    break;
                case 'dsfirewall_uploadfilesys':
                    {
                    isset($modules[1]['dsfirewall_allow'])?$v_allow_select = $modules[1]['dsfirewall_allow']:$v_allow_select = '0';
                        
                        if ($v_allow_select == "0")
                        {
                        echo '<td class="off">'.$ds_firewall_statistic_8.'</td>';
                        }
                        if ($v_allow_select == "1")
                        {
                        echo '<td class="on" >'.$ds_firewall_statistic_7.'</td>';
                        } 
                        if ($v_allow_select == "2")
                        {
                        echo '<td class="on" >'.$ds_firewall_statistic_7.'</td>';
                        } 
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                   {
                    if (!isset($modules[1][$n_setting])){
                    $modules[1][$n_setting]="0";
                    }
                    
                    if ($modules[1][$n_setting]){
                    echo '<td class="on" >'.$ds_firewall_statistic_7.'</td>';
                    } else {
                    echo '<td class="off">'.$ds_firewall_statistic_8.'</td>';
                    }
                   }
            }
            
            
        
            //var_dump($n_setting);

?>
            <td><?php echo $value[0]['num_incidents'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $value[0]['date_lastincidents'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $value[0]['ip'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $value[0]['security_info'];?></td>   
        </tr>   
        <?php } ?>
        
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: `$$value[0]['security_name']` you need to split this issue into 2 parts. Right part `$value[0]['security_name']` which return string and then the left part `${string which you get in right part` which will be the name of the variable to which you are trying to refer. And yes i don't see any `$Array` variable in the template as error mentioning. Probably you need to remove `$` sign to the left.

Comment: Thank you for response. But I didn't get it. I'm not programmer (

Comment: instead of this `$$value[0]['security_name']` put this `$value[0]['security_name']`. Remove one `$` dollar sign on line 36

Comment: This solution actually perfect working. No more errors. Thank you very much!

Comment: Faced another problem after removing the $ symbol. Language variables are not displayed. It's in PHP 7.4
Help please, what needs to be changed to work on PHP 7.4?    1 dsfirewall_cookies    
2 dsfirewall_bots    
3 dsfirewall_xss    
4 dsfirewall_dos    
5 dsfirewall_sql    
6 dsfirewall_worm    
7 dsfirewall_get    
8 dsfirewall_post    
9 dsfirewall_server    
10 dsfirewall_protectionurl